# Nvidia Container causing audio popping and Explorer lag

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-explorer, nvidia-graphics-card, latency

I have been having this issue where my audio starts popping and crackling quite frequently (tried various audio devices, not specific to one device) and Windows Explorer generally becomes laggy and stuttery when doing nothing but hovering over items.

Only fix I found was killing "Nvidia Container" (related to NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem service). This instantly fixed the audio issues, explorer lag and LatencyMon shows no issues.

Any idea what the problem could be? It did not have any CPU usage and barely any ram usage. The only downside I've found so far is that I can't open the Nvidia Control Panel anymore, and I'd like to actually use ShadowPlay on GeForce experience, will this affect it too?

Additional information:

Windows 10 20H2, i9 9600k, 32GB RAM, RTX 3080, Nvidia Driver 461.09 (recently updated but had this issue before the update), GeForce Experience is uninstalled.

A reboot fixes it temporarily but it always comes back after 2-3 days tops. I've also been testing with LatencyMon and it also shows the same pattern of being fine after a reboot but having massive spikes after a few days. It often shows "ndis.sys" and "nvlddmkm.sys".

For troubleshooting, I've completely re-installed GPU drivers as well as updates BIOS and all other drivers, and eventually started killing processes one by one to see if any would solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a known issue with DPC Latency, which should finally be fixed: https://www.tomshardware.com/news/nvidias-new-geforce-driver-claimed-to-fix-dpc-latency-issues

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).